# How to find a real range of the sheet using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, google-sheets-api

I need help in determining the real range of my spreadsheet as I don't know the last row number as the data as it gets imported from an external source. I am creating a small program to find if a certain columns have a "null" value and send the details to Slack. Once I reach an empty row, I need to terminate the code. Attaching a small screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVleD.png)

Now, I have tried creating a range variable but the script runs till the end and sends the message on Slack even though there is no data in the last rows. I need it to stop once it reaches the end of the data, like 29th row in the screenshot. Below is my code -

```
public static void ReadEntries() 
{
    var range = $ "{Sheet}!A3:AW28";
    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
      _service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);

    var response = request.Execute();

    IList < IList < object >> values = response.Values;
    if (values != null && values.Count > 0) {
      foreach(var row in values) {

        var n = 0;
        if (row[n].ToString().Trim() == null) {
          break;
        }

        //var rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

        //Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", row[45], row[46], row[47], row[48]);

        //if (row[n] == "-")
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
        //else if (row[n].ToString().Trim()== "null" && n<49)
        {
          var client1 = new RestClient("<slack webhook>");
          client1.Timeout = -1;
          var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
          var body = "<message_payload>";
          request1.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

          //IRestResponse response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
          if (row[i].ToString().Trim() == "null") {
            Console.WriteLine("OK" + i);
          } else if (row[i].ToString().Trim() == "") {
            Console.WriteLine("Its Over" + i);
          }

          //Thread.Sleep(1000);
          //n++;
        }
      }
    } else {
   Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
}
```

Now, I have tried creating a range variable but the script runs till the end and sends the message on Slack even though there is no data in the last rows. I need it to stop once it reaches the end of the data, like 29th row in the screenshot. I have tried searching for an answer and found a line that can find the last row and probably the real range of my spreadsheet, but it does not work for some reason -

`var rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;`

I have also tried to identify a blank column by converting the response cell to string like this -

```
 if (row[n].ToString().Trim() == null)
 { 
  break;
 }
```

But I don't think it is working correctly. I am really sorry if I did not explain it properly, english is not my first language but I will try to share more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[n]?.ToString().Trim()))
{
break;
```

or

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
```

Try like that

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you seek: (not sure)

```
function myfunk() {
  const sh  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = `${sh.getName()}!${sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation()}`;
  Logger.log(rg);
  return rg;
}
```